# Writing an implementation of removeAll in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on the following question:

Write a method removeAll that takes an integer value as a parameter and that removes all occurrences of the given value from the list.

My code doesn't check all the elements in the array. It works fine When I change "size" in the for loop to the number of integers in the array.  It checks all of them.

```
public class ArrayIntList { 
    private int[] elementData;
    private int size;
}


public void remove(int index) {

    for(int i = index; i < size-1; i++) {
        elementData[i] = elementData[i+1];
    }
    size--;
}

public void removeAll(int num) {

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {// this loop doesn't check all the elements

        if (elementData[j] == num) {
            remove(j);
        } 

    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: Run the loop 'backwards'

Answer (score 1):

If you are removing elements, you need to decrement `j` otherwise you skip over elements.

```
remove(j);
j--;
```

Alternatively, if you iterate from the end to the start, you don't have to alter the counter because you've already processed those elements.

```
 for (int j = size - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if (elementData[j] == num) {
          remove(j);
     } 
 }
```